# Multiple outputs of same file using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript project that uses a lot of utility functions for both the front-end and backend. I need one file to end up in the 'dist' directory using typescript and commonJs and the other to be compiled with ES6 in the 'public' directory so my React functions have access to these utilities.

Currently I have 2 tsconfig.json files using a reference as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["public", "node_modules", "dist"],
  "references": [{ "path": "src/helpers/shared-functions" }]
}
```

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "../../../public/shared-functions",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": false
  }
}
```

For some reason my "src/helpers/shared-functions" is not building into "dist/helpers/shared-functions" as expected even though the rest of the project builds fine as well as my output to "public/shared-functions"

How can ensure the "src/helpers/shared-functions" gets built into the "dist" directory as expected.